# String Concatenation in URL

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, active-model-serializers

**TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "builtin_function_or_method") to str**

In line No. 5:

```
resp = requests.get(BASE_URL + ENDPOINT + id + '/')
```

**My Code:**

```
import requests
BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
ENDPOINT = 'api/'
def get_resource(id):
    resp = requests.get(BASE_URL + ENDPOINT + id + '/')
    print(resp.status_code)
    data = resp.json()
    print(data)
get_resource(id)
```

Comment: What is the value of id ?

Comment: id holds integer

Comment: convert the integer value using `str(id)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that you are calling `get_resource()` with argument `id` and value of `id` is not defined anywhere.

You need to assign a string to id. If you are passing an integer then use `str(id)` to convert it to string.

```py
resp = requests.get(BASE_URL + ENDPOINT + str(id) + '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need pass the id as string, if you using python > 3.6, you can use the f string for the string con-cation

```
resp = requests.get(f"{BASE_URL}{ENDPOINT}{id}/")
```